# Python find if strings are anagram of each other string

Tags: python, algorithm, while-loop

I am trying to solve the above interview question to check if string are anagram of each other. The implementation is as follows:

```
NO_OF_CHARS = 256
def areAnagram(str1, str2):
    count = [0] * NO_OF_CHARS
    i = 0
    while (i in str1) and (i in str2):
        count[ord(i)]+=1
        i += 1
    if len(str1) != len(str2):
        return 0
    for i in xrange(NO_OF_CHARS):
        if count[i]:
            return 0
    return 1

str1 = "geeksforgeeks"
str2 = "forgeeksgeeks"
if areAnagram(str1, str2):
    print "The two strings are anagram of each other"
else:
    print "The two strings are not anagram of each other"
```

I am getting the following error while running the code:

```
TypeError: 'In <string> requires string as left operand
```

Am I doing something wrong in the while loop? Also, how can I avoid to use i = 0 statement? Thanks.

Comment: There's a _much_ simpler way to test for anagrams. You don't need to count the chars like that.

Comment: Sure..But using this example trying to understand the behavior of while loop involving 2 strings

Comment: Stepping through the code first would be a good step. https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Thanks @PaulHankin. I am following the above code. But trying to find the work around while loop with 2 string in python. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: @deep check out Python Debugger [pdb](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html) to set a break point and step through your code at runtime

Comment: The error you have is in the while loop, according to your code, i in `while (i ...` should be `string` type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to go for counting the characters, you need to make counts for both strings and compare them

```
NO_OF_CHARS = 256
def areAnagram(str1, str2):
    if len(str1) != len(str2):
        return 0
    count = [0] * NO_OF_CHARS
    for c1,c2 in zip(str1,str2):
        count[ord(c1)] +=1
        count[ord(c2)] -=1
    return all(not c for c in count)
```

I moved checking the length of strings to the beginning of the method for efficiency and clarity

**EDIT:** Updated my answer according to Blckknght's comment

Comment: How about using a single count list? Thanks

Comment: What would you store in a single count list that could determine if the 2 strings are anagrams? Your intent wasn't clear to me from the original post, if count[i]: returns True if the count is not 0

Comment: @deep Note this algo is O(N^2) in best case.

Comment: @Natecat this algorithm is `Ω( len )` in the best case, which is probably `Ω(k)` due to `len(str1) != len(str2)`.

Comment: @Centril Sorry, meant average case

Comment: You could make this work with a single count. Add one to the count for each character in `str1` and subtract one for each character in `str2`. If the count list is all zeros at the end, they're anagrams.

Comment: What @Blckknght said was NOT to use `sum`, but rather: `return ∀c ∈ count : c = 0`.

Comment: After updating `sum(count) == 0` is not more valid criteria. Sum abs values or check for non-zeros

Comment: Why not just `return all(not c for c in count)`? Or an explicit check that fails on the first non-zero element in count?

Comment: `not any(count)` is probably a little better, since you don't need the generator expression.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of either function

Comment: @Blckknght true, that is more concise =) @Natecat please explain why this algorithm has avg time complexity `n^2`... I'd say it is rather `O(max(str1, str2))` with `Ω(k)` with the space complexity `Θ(256) = Θ(1)`.

Comment: If the lengths aren't equal the algorithm fails early

Comment: By the way... the assumption everyone is making that `NO_OF_CHARS = 256` is highly dubious and will not work with unicode... for an algorithm that works even with unicode you should either use a real hash map or simply use @jordan-bonitatis solution `sorted(list(src)) == sorted(list(trgt))`.

Comment: Good points, @Centril. However, the OP is using Python 2, so the strings are just simple ASCII / byte strings and cannot contain Unicode. Of course, the sensible way to do an anagram test is to compare the sorted strings.

Comment: @Blckknght: `not any(count)` is definitely superior to `all(not c for c in count)`, since the latter requires a loop running at Python speed, whereas the loop in the former happens at C speed. The speed difference will be negligible for this small list, but why use longer, slower code when you can easily use shorter, faster code? :)

Comment: @PM 2Ring Could you link to the python documentation (or something else) where the difference in the execution of the 2 commands is described?

Comment: @GiannisPapadopoulos: Sorry, I don't have any doc links, but here's a [speed comparison test](http://pastebin.com/4H5u2A9B) I just wrote. The `not any` version is roughly 10 times faster than the `all(genexp)` version, although that drops to around 5 times faster if the first non-zero is found early in `count`. `all` and `any` are _very_ similar in how they work internally. The main speed difference here is due to `all` iterating over a generator expression.

Comment: FWIW, the C source code for the standard CPython implementation of `all` and `any` can be found [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/bltinmodule.c#L262).

Answer (score 4):

An easy way to see if strings are comprised of the same characters is to compare them as sorted lists:

```
def is_anagram(src, trgt):
    """
    Determine if trgt is an anagram of src
    :param src: (str)
    :param trgt: (str)
    :returns: (bool) True if trgt is an anagram of src; else False
    """
    return sorted(src) == sorted(trgt)
```

Comment: Is performance a requirement here?  This is a good illustration for the importance of communicating non-functional requirements ;-)

Comment: @deep so just use a sorting algorithm with `O(n log(n))` instead of `O(n^2)` if the performance is not good enough.

Comment: @deep No, sorted is O(n log n)

Comment: @Centril> or just use a sorting algorithm in `O(1)`, you'll be much faster! Surely there must be a conspiracy out there for everyone to use n·log n sorts.

Comment: @spectras there is no general case sorting algorithm performing better than `O(n log(n))` in the worst case which sorts correctly. However, there might be algorithms that performs better in the average case (theta). And you should also take constant factors into account. See mergesort vs. quicksort for example.

Comment: @Centril> I know, I know, that was related to the typo before you edited ;)

Comment: Is there a reason for the `list` calls inside the `sorted` calls? The `sorted` function works on any iterable, not only on lists.

Comment: @Blckknght - you're totally right!  I'm going to update the answer to reflect this.  Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The canonical way to do this in Python is to use `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

def areAnagram(str1, str2):
    return Counter(str1) == Counter(str2)
```

This should take `O(N)` space and time (where `N` is `max(len(str1), len(str2))`). But do be aware that even though this code's asymptotic performance is better, it may still be slower for short strings than a version using `sorted`. Python's `sort` code is very fast!

If you're likely to be using the function to compare very-unlike strings, you could perhaps it up a little bit with a special case checking the string lengths before counting:

```
def areAnagram(str1, str2):
    return len(str1) == len(str2) and Counter(str1) == Counter(str2)
```

Comment: This should've been the chosen answer...(+1). I actually learned from this one.